# Logo image overlay on menu bar to stick out above and below menu bar

Tags: html, css

I have a menu bar with height 20px, my logo is 150x150px. 
I want to vertically align my logo such that it sticks out on top and below my menu bar. Thus 65px above my menu bar and 65px below my menu bar. Now my menu bar height adjusts correspondingly with the height of my logo image, so the menu bar entirely expands from 20px to 150px. Is it possible to achieve my goal since the logo is part of the menu bar, but also not in a way?
[image]

Fiddle[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rabas007/hr064mjz/)

HTML:

```
<div id="nav">
        <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static">
            <div class="menu-container">
                <!-- .btn-navbar is used as the toggle for collapsed navbar content -->
                <a class="navbar-toggle" data-target=".navbar-collapse"
                data-toggle="collapse"><span class=
                "glyphicon glyphicon-bar"></span> <span class=
                "glyphicon glyphicon-bar"></span> <span class=
                "glyphicon glyphicon-bar"></span></a> <a class="navbar-brand"
                href="#"><img alt="" src=
                "http://placehold.it/150x150&text=Logo"></a>

                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.navbar -->
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.menu-container {
    background-color:#000000;
}

#nav.affix {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    z-index:10
}

#sidebar.affix-top {
    position:static
}

#sidebar.affix {
    position:fixed;
    top:80px
}
```

Comment: Kindly let me know your exact requirement cannot understand how it needs to be positioned?? is there any sample screenshots of it

Comment: @Sai Deepak - Hi Sai - I added an image for better explanation. Please note that my menu affixes to top when scrolling down, so the logo-image has to be part of that feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?  It's hard to tell exactly what you are looking to achieve.  The code is a little sloppy, but this should do it.

CSS

```
html,body{
  margin:0;
  background:#ccc;
}
#cont{
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  height:150px;
  background:transparent;
}
ul{
  position:relative;
  top:65px;
  width:100%;
  height:20px;
  background:#444;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
li:first-child{
  /*to adjust left spaceing*/
  margin-left:50px;
}
li{
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  top:0;
  width:150px;
  height:20px;
  background:#333;
  line-height:20px;
  text-align:center;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

.elem{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  width:100%;
  height:20px;
  background:#333;
}

.logo{
  top:-65px !important;
  height:150px !important;
  line-height:150px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.elem:hover{
  top:-65px !important;
  height:150px !important;
  line-height:150px;  
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="cont">
  <ul id="bar">
     <li>
       <div class="elem logo">
         <img src="http://www.battleoftastings.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/seafood-placeholder150x150px.png"/>
       </div>
     </li>
     <li>
       <div class="elem">
         Home
       </div>
     </li>
     <li>
       <div class="elem">
        About
       </div>
     </li>
     <li>
       <div class="elem">
        Contact
       </div>
     </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Example:
[CodePen](http://codepen.io/dclappert/pen/oXjdqm)

Comment: Thanks, David. Sorry about the code, you are right, I trimmed it down to the bare necessary. Your solution works, but do you know if I scroll down and the menu affixes to the top that the logo part above the menu bar does not get clipped and thus disappears (which is then half my logo thats gone)?Basically I want the whole logo to affix to the top when my menu bar affixes to the top. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: Oh, I see.  You want both the logo and the nav bar affixed to the top?  So really you envision two "states".  One where both the logo and nav bar are affixed to the top, and another state where the logo is still affixed to the top but the nav bar is centered on the logo?  Your illustration being the later state.

Comment: Check the CodePen again.  It's scrollable.

Comment: exactly! You nailed it, perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[Jsfiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/Im_Saajan/hr064mjz/2/)

```
#nav {
    position:fixed;
    top:65px;
    width:100%;
    z-index:10;
    height:20px;
    background-color:#000000;
 }  

#nav img{
     position:fixed;
     top:0px;
 }
```

by going through your question i could design this jsfiddle. Hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: cannot open your link

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience ... try the link now

Comment: thanks, but when I scroll down and the menu bar affixes to the top, then the logo-part above the menu-bar gets clipped and disappears. How to fix that such that when scrolling down the entire logo (including top-part) always shows?

Comment: actually the code whatever i posted will work .. it doesn't clip the logo and menu bar...

Answer (score 0):

You have to use position absolute on logo div so that It doesn't affect the menu height...

Answer (score 0):

```
#nav{  margin: 65px 0;}
.menu-container{  min-height: 20px;
  position: relative;}
.navbar-brand{  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -75px;}
```

[Fiddle for how it works](http://jsfiddle.net/rabas007/hr064mjz/)

Comment: thanks, but when I scroll down and the menu bar affixes to the top, then the logo-part above the menu-bar gets clipped and disappears. How to fix that such that when scrolling down the entire logo (including top-part) always shows?

Comment: In that case try this way

#nav{position: fixed; min-height: 20px;  /* position: relative; */
  width: 100%;margin: 65px 0;background: #000;}

.navbar-brand{  display: inline-block;  position: absolute;  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -75px;}

remove .main-container style from it

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
.menu-container {
 background-color:#000000;
}

.navbar-brand {position:absolute;margin-top:-60px;}

.navbar-collapse {
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-left: 120px;
    color: #fff;
}

#nav.affix {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    z-index:10
}

#sidebar.affix-top {
    position:static
}

#sidebar.affix {
    position:fixed;
    top:80px
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
        <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static">
            <div class="menu-container">
                <!-- .btn-navbar is used as the toggle for collapsed navbar content -->
                <a class="navbar-toggle" data-target=".navbar-collapse"
                data-toggle="collapse"><span class=
                "glyphicon glyphicon-bar"></span> <span class=
                "glyphicon glyphicon-bar"></span> <span class=
                "glyphicon glyphicon-bar"></span></a> <a class="navbar-brand"
                href="#"><img alt="" src=
                "http://placehold.it/150x150&text=Logo"></a>

                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                 <ul>
                     <li>Home</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.navbar -->
    </div>
```

I add new class in css just check...

Comment: thanks, but when I scroll down and the menu bar affixes to the top, then the logo-part above the menu-bar gets clipped and disappears. How to fix that such that when scrolling down the entire logo (including top-part) always shows?